# PostgreSQL: month := interval '30 days';

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Trying to delete records older than 1 month from 2 tables, where 1 references the "id" column in another:

```
create or replace function quincytrack_clean()
        returns void as $BODY$
        begin
                month := interval '30 days';

                delete from hide_id
                where id in
                (select id from quincytrack
                where age(QDATETIME) > month);

                delete from quincytrack
                where age(QDATETIME) > month;
        end;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

but this fails with:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "month"
LINE 1: month := interval '30 days'
        ^
QUERY:  month := interval '30 days'
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "quincytrack_clean" near line 2
```

I'm reading [the doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html), but don't understand what's wrong with my declaration...

Comment: 1 month is not the same as 30 days: 12 months = 1 year, 12 * 30 days = 360 days, 5 or 6 days less than a full year. Use '1 month' when you need 1 month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the variable 'month', viz.:

```
declare
    month interval;
begin
    month := interval '30 days';
end;
```

Also, you might want to re-examine your "where" criteria. If QDATETIME is an indexed column, I don't think it will use the index, whereas `QDATETIME < (now() - month)` would.

Comment: Thanks. I thought DECLARE is only for declaring the procedure parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the variable before you can use it.

```
...
DECLARE
   month INTERVAL;
BEGIN 
   month := interval '30 days';
 ...
```

But I would avoid using variable names that are reserved words or internal function names.

Comment: his interval syntax is correct. `interval '30' days` isn't a valid expression... `select interval '30' days` produces a column called `days` with a value of 30 seconds...

Comment: `interval '30' day` is the ANSI standard and is supported by PostgreSQL  (I tested my code with PostgreSQL 9.0). But it seems that PostgreSQL also supports the way the OP wrote it which I didn't know.

Comment: ` do $$ declare month interval; begin month := interval '30' days; raise info '%', month; end; $$; ` - prints an interval of 30 seconds.

Comment: Interesting. It seems that this is handled differently in different environments. When using `select interval '3' days` with a JDBC tool, I correctly get an interval output (`0 years 0 mons 3 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs`), whereas with psql I indeed get a single column named days with an interval of 3 seconds. Very, very strange

Comment: OK, I think I found the reason for the different behaviour. The ANSI standard is indeed `interval '3' day` (note the singular day) as far as I can tell after reading the specs. And if used like that `select interval '3' day` psql returns a correct interval as well. It seems that when using `days` (plural) this is not recognized as an interval unit, therefor the default unit (which is seconds)  is used and `days` is used as the column alias. So it's just the matter of adding an `s`. In my initial post I pasted the original and forgot to remove the `s` at the end.

Comment: For the sake of completeness (or something), I'll just point out that in PostgreSQL, the intervals `'3' DAY`, `'3 DAY'`, and `'3 DAYS'` all behave the same.