# Calculating a date in Postgres by adding months?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres table that has the following fields

**start_date,duration**

duration contains any number of months, so to calculate the end date you add the months in duration to the start date. Now I want to do something like this with a postgres query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE start_date > '2010-05-12' 
AND (start_date + duration) < '2010-05-12'
```

Is this possible and how does one right the syntax?

The version of my postgres is  **PostgreSQL 8.1.22 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)**

Comment: 8.1 ? You should really upgrade ! If "duration" is of type INTERVAL then it will work, if it's an integer number of months you have to do "duration * '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL".

Comment: @pefeu: you should make that an answer.

Comment: @peufeu - 8.1 is the default version [on RHEL5](http://blog.endpoint.com/2010/09/postgresql-84-in-rhelcentos-55.html). It is stable and will be supported by Red Hat until [at least 2014](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux#Life_Cycle_Dates). In some cases that matters a lot more than having the latest version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try:

```
(start_date + (duration * '1 month'::INTERVAL)) < '2010-05-12'
```

or

```
(start_date + (duration || ' month')::INTERVAL) < '2010-05-12'
```

More info: [*Date/Time Functions and Operators*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: = Getting Syntax ERROR:  syntax error at or near "duration" at character 220

Answer (score 1):

You might find this article useful: [PostgreSQL: month := interval '30 days';](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713490/postgresql-month-interval-30-days)

Also this link: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL, more specifically the section called "WORKING with DATETIME, DATE, and INTERVAL VALUES".