# Adding months to a date in PostgreSQL shows syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I am using Postgres 9.0 version. I want to add some months to a date to calculate the new date and update in a table. Here the number of months to be added will be in integer variable. My code is as follows:

```
declare numberofmonths smallint = 5;
update salereg1 set expdate = current_date + interval cast(numberofmonths as text) month;
```

The above code shows syntax error at cast. I don't know how to specify the `numberofmonths` variable as text.. can anyone help me. what is the mistake I did..

Comment: Does this: [Calculating a date in Postgres by adding months?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909363/calculating-a-date-in-postgres-by-adding-months) help?

Comment: You should be aware of some peculiarities of our calendar when adding months. What date should be 1 month from 2013-01-28, 2013-01-29, 2013-01-30 or 2013-01-31? Postgres by default will return 2013-02-28 for all 4 dates. Also 12 months from 2012-02-29? 2012 was a leap year, Postgres would return 2013-02-28.

Answer (score 88):

Try something like:

```
update salereg1 
set expdate = current_date + interval '1 month' * numberofmonths;
```

Comment: +1 I like this one more than mine. May be I'd write this as `'1 month'::interval * numberofmonths`also.

Comment: thanks very helpful specially for those who are new to postgres.

Answer (score 16):

Something like this:

```
update salereg1 set
    expdate = current_date + (numberofmonths::text || ' month')::interval;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/07e14/2)</kbd>**

Comment: This is a great trick for the case where the interval value itself to be used is dynamic text +1.

Comment: refer to the other answer, you don't have to cast to text it can multiply the interval directly

Comment: yes if you use `interval '1 month' * n`. In my answer I was building interval dynamically to get `'{n} month'::interval`. As said in the comment I like first approach more.

Answer (score 6):

Since Postgres 9.4 you can also use the handy function [`make_interval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.14.5.2.2.23.1.1):

```
update salereg1 
  set expdate = current_date + make_interval(months => numberofmonths);
```

Answer (score 2):

Understanding it from this analogy between SQL Server and PostgreSQL

SQL Server:
-- Get expiration date

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, valid, purchased) FROM licenses;
```

PostgreSQL:
-- Get expiration date

```
SELECT purchased + valid * INTERVAL '1 DAY' FROM licenses;
```

Similarly   `current_date + number_of_months * INTERVAL '1 MONTH';` so the INTERVAL can be '1 MONTH',  '1 DAY',  '1 YEAR' like that.

more on this page [PostgreSQL - DATEADD - Add Interval to Datetime](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/dateadd)